# Using a loop to preform actions on an array, that is being used as a selector

Tags: jquery, css

My thought is that it would be something like this:

```
var ads = newArray[];

ads[0] = "#classes";
ads[1] = "#fluke";
ads[2] = "#pelican";

for (i = 0, i <= 2, i++) {
    $(ads[i]).delay(1500).show();
}
```

It's a really rough idea of what I'm looking at doing. Eventually, I'm looking to make it scroll through ads for the site. Somehow, I'm tripping up on the logic of it. As it is, I would expect this code to delay 1500, then show ALL the divs. The ultimate goal is to show them one after another.

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong. It should have semicolons, not commas.

Comment: Also, array literal syntax is nice and better in just about every way. `['#classes', '#fluke', '#pelican']`

Comment: @dunsmoeb: The question is, how do I make this work properly? From what I'm used to with other languages I would think this would work but it wont.

Comment: @minitech missed that, thank you. Also, I have a habit of writing things out then condensing it later. Just makes more sense to me when I'm trying to pound the idea out.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not
>   use the effects queue.

The following should get around this as it triggers the *effects queue*. Adjust the argument for `show()` to your liking.

```
$('#target1').delay(1500).show('fast');
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZFjr/).

As an aside, there's no reason to build an array. You can select multiple elements at once:

```
$('#target1, #target2').show();
```

See [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZFjr/1/).

Comment: Since the ultimate idea is to do one element, then delay, then do another element, I thought it would be better to use an array then cycle through the variables... is this not the case? Thanks for the heads up on that though. In this case, I would more likely assign a universal class to the affected elements so I didn't have to select multiple elements deliberately.

Comment: None of the code provided here will achieve the effect you just described (appearing in sequence). I addressed your issue with `delay()`. As far as identifying the elements, I would suggest using a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var loopStart = '0';
var loopEnd = '3';
$('#class').css({display: 'inline-block'});
function adLoop() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (loopStart+1 == 1 && loopStart+2 == 2) {
                $('#fluke').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#pelican').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#class').css({display: 'inline-block'});
            }
            if (loopStart+1 == 2 && loopStart+2 == 3) {
                $('#class').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#pelican').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#fluke').css({display: 'inline-block'});
            }
            if (loopStart+1 == 3 && loopStart+2 == 4) {
                $('#class').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#fluke').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#pelican').css({display: 'inline-block'});
            }
            if (loopStart+1 == 4 && loopStart+2 == 5) {
                $('#fluke').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#pelican').css({display: 'none'});
                $('#class').css({display: 'inline-block'});
                loopStart = 0;
            }
            loopStart++;
            if (loopStart <= loopEnd) {
                adLoop();
            }
        }, 5000)
}
adLoop();
})
```

This is what I've come up with. I'd like to do the same thing with an array.